# Updation on DB with the different categories in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am creating a project related to Leave Absence. Leave will be maintained & manipulated according to the different categories.

Every Flow of concept is working, except calculating Leave Days & Showing Balance.

I have created a Model Named,
**LeaveReq.CS**

```
public class LeaveReq
{
    public int ID {get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Employee Name")]
    public string emp_name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Requested Day")]
    public string day_ctg { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime startdt { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "End Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime enddt { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Time-Off Category")]
    public string category { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Applied On")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime apply { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Balance")]
    public string bal { get; set; }

}
```

and The screen would like,

[image: Apply Leave]

I have created a Model Named, **TimeOffSettigs.CS**

```
public class TimeOffSettigs
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Time-Off Type")]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Time-Off Category")]
    public string category { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Maximum Allowance")]
    public int allowance { get; set; }
}
```

The Screen Would, Look Like
[image: TimeOffSettings]

Basic Concept is that, When an employee applies for Leave in a category. His Balance leave should be shown. On applying, Certain allowance should be deducted from his remaining balance.

For Example. If I am applying leave in Vacation & Full Day (8Hrs).
Allowance for Vacation is 80hrs.
On applying leave for First Time. My balance be stored as (80-8) 72Hours.
On Applying next time as half a day(4hrs). My Balance should be stored as (72-4) 68Hrs in DB

I have written a code, for this concept in **Controller.CS**

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Approve")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LvDetailsConfirmed(int id)
    {
        LeaveReq levreq = dblv.Leave_Dts.Find(id);
        TimeOffSettigs timesettings = dbts.policy_tbl.Find(id);

        if (levreq.bal == null)
        {
            if (levreq.day_ctg == "Full Day")
            {
                var bal_full = 8;
                levreq.bal = (timesettings.allowance - bal_full).ToString();
            }
            else if (levreq.day_ctg == "Partial Day")
            {
                var bal_par = 4;
                levreq.bal = (timesettings.allowance - bal_par).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                var timespan = levreq.enddt.Subtract(levreq.startdt);
                var dayscalc = timespan.Days;
                var bal_mul = 8 * dayscalc;
                levreq.bal = (timesettings.allowance - bal_mul).ToString();
            }
        }

        else
        {
            if (levreq.day_ctg == "Full Day")
            {
                var bal_full = 8;
                levreq.bal = (Convert.ToInt32(levreq.bal) - bal_full).ToString();
            }
            else if (levreq.day_ctg == "Partial Day")
            {
                var bal_par = 4;
                levreq.bal = (Convert.ToInt32(levreq.bal) - bal_par).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                var timespan = levreq.enddt.Subtract(levreq.startdt);
                var dayscalc = timespan.Days;
                var bal_mul = 8 * dayscalc;
                levreq.bal = (Convert.ToInt32(levreq.bal) - bal_mul).ToString();
            }
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            dblv.Entry(levreq).State = EntityState.Modified;
            dblv.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("ELeave");
        }
        return View(levreq);
```

Approval/Request Screen will be looking like,

[image: Approve/Reject]

On clicking Approve, Balance should be Deducted.
On Clicking Reject, Balance shouldnt be deducted.

Don't know, what is the wrong I did in controller. whenever I press Approve, Nothing change happening in DB.

This is the Approval Button Code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <input type="submit" value="Approve" class="btn btn-default" name="aprbtn" /> |
        <input type="submit" value="Reject" class="btn btn-default" name="rejbtn"/>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "ELeave")
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Is this button click hit the controller action ? or debug the code

Comment: @Nazir Yes, It hits the controller Action

Comment: [HttpPost, ActionName("Approve")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LvDetailsConfirmed(int id)

Comment: debug the code and check may some if condition not allowing to db

Answer (score 0):

Give name to button and then check.

```
<input type="submit" value="Approve" class="btn btn-default" name="Approve" />
```

Comment: Still No Change :-(

Comment: db reference for Class

Comment: please define on your controller Like Your " Classname dblv= new Classname() ";